# WP_query 'orderby' with array and if first variable value missing then put last and only sort that by the second variable

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, advanced-custom-fields, order

Some of my Custom Post Type (CPT) 'player' has a value entered for ACF field 'player_personal_player_number', some 'players' do not have a number.

Trying to display the 'players' by number (ASC) first followed by 'title'. So that we run through all the digits first, and what is left goes at the end in alphabetical 'title' order.

For some reason what I have doesn't move numberless players to the end. They are alpha sorted yes, but are displayed before numbered players.

The ACF key can sometimes be there or not, so we have to check the value for 'player_personal_player_number' and not if the key exists.

Can anyone see where I made the mistake?

```
add_filter( 'fl_builder_loop_query_args', 'player_fl_builder_loop_query_args_filter' );
function player_fl_builder_loop_query_args_filter( $query_args ) {
    // target this post module ID
    if ( 'player_list' == $query_args['settings']->id ) {

        $query_args['meta_key'] = 'player_personal_player_number';
        //$query_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';   // sort by single
        $query_args['orderby'] = array (
            'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',              // Order by 'player_personal_player_number' numerically in ascending order
            'title'             => 'ASC',           // Then order by post title alphabetically
            );   // sort by as array
        //now we check to see if player_number is empty and if so, put them at the end
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'player_personal_player_number',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'player_personal_player_number',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'player_personal_player_number',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        );
 
  }

  return $query_args;
}
```